# Java generics class defined as return type or at class level?

Tags: java, generics, types

In cases where a method returns a generic, is there any benefit to declaring the generic class as a return type compared to just declaring at the class level?

```
    //case #1
    public interface Reaper<T> {
        <S extends Foo> S save(S entity);
        <S extends Foo> S saveWithOptions(S entity, Object[] params);
    }
```

.

```
    //case #2
    public interface Reaper<T, S extends Foo> {   
        S save(S entity);
        S saveWithOptions(S entity, Object[] params);
    }
```

In case #2, I don't have to repeat `<S extends Foo>` for each method that returns `S` since it's declared in the interface, although when it comes to usage I'll have to define as `Reaper<MyType, MyFooSubType>`. Beyond that, is there any major difference and/or benefit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare it at the class level, you can't call the functions with different type parameters on the same class instance.
In other words, the type becomes a property of the instance, rather than a property of each function call.

Answer (score 1):

Use case is a bit different. Usage on class level will guarantee you consistency(type restriction) on all methods.